# Redshift Convert UNIX Timestamp to YYYYMMDD, Collect Cumulative Count, and Group by Date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Theres a few things going on here. Ill lay out my logic below:

1. Select categorical columns
2. Convert unix timestamp:

   date_trunc('day', TIMESPAMP 'epoch' + time_column * INTERVAL '1 second'
3. Collect a cumulative count of categorical column

   count(categorical_column) OVER (PARTITION BY categorical_column ORDER BY date ASC ROW UNBOUNDED PRECEEDING)
4. GROUP BY date_column, categorical_column

The issue I'm running into is I'm only getting 1 count per day when there are multiple occurrences on a single day. Any suggestions?

```
SELECT cat_col_1, 
       cat_col_2, 
       date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + time_col * INTERVAL '1 second'), 
       count(cat_col_1) OVER (PARTITION BY cat_col_1 ORDER BY time_col ROW UNBOUNDED PRECEEDING)
FROM example_table
GROUP BY time_col, cat_col_1, cat_col_2
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Wrap count(cat_col_1) in sum()

```
SELECT cat_col_1, 
       cat_col_2, 
       date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + time_col * INTERVAL '1 second'), 
       sum(count(cat_col_1)) OVER (PARTITION BY cat_col_1 ORDER BY time_col ROW UNBOUNDED PRECEEDING)
FROM example_table
GROUP BY time_col, cat_col_1, cat_col_2
```